# Can't install egenix-mx-base on Django production VPS

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment, ubuntu-8.04

I have been following these [instructions](http://lethain.com/entry/2009/feb/13/the-django-and-ubuntu-intrepid-almanac/) for setting up a Django production server with postgres, apache, nginx, and memcache. My problem is that I cannot get egenix-mx-base to install and without this I cannot get psycopg2 to work and therefore no database access :(.

I am attempting this on a VPS running a clean install of Ubuntu Hardy (8.04) and have followed all instructions on the site to a T.

The error message is as follows:

```
$ easy_install egenix-mx-base
Searching for egenix-mx-base
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/egenix-mx-base/
Reading http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/
Reading http://www.lemburg.com/python/mxExtensions.html
Reading http://www.egenix.com/
Best match: egenix-mx-base 3.1.3
Downloading http://downloads.egenix.com/python/egenix-mx-base-3.1.3.tar.gz
Processing egenix-mx-base-3.1.3.tar.gz
Running egenix-mx-base-3.1.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-iF7qzl/egenix-mx-base-3.1.3/egg-dist-tmp-laxvcS
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules _winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.
In file included from mx/TextTools/mxTextTools/mxte.c:42:
mx/TextTools/mxTextTools/mxte_impl.h: In function ‘mxTextTools_TaggingEngine’:
mx/TextTools/mxTextTools/mxte_impl.h:345: warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness
mx/TextTools/mxTextTools/mxte_impl.h:364: warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness
mx/URL/mxURL/mxURL.c: In function ‘mxURL_SetFromString’:
mx/URL/mxURL/mxURL.c:676: warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness
mx/UID/mxUID/mxUID.c: In function ‘mxUID_Verify’:
mx/UID/mxUID/mxUID.c:333: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘sscanf’ differ in signedness
mx/UID/mxUID/mxUID.c: In function ‘mxUID_New’:
mx/UID/mxUID/mxUID.c:462: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘mxUID_CRC16’ differ in signedness
error: Setup script exited with error: build/bdist.linux-x86_64-py2.5_ucs4/dumb/egenix_mx_base-3.1.3-py2.5.egg-info: Is a directory
```

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to try to help me.

Answer (score 3):

Install it manually:

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://downloads.egenix.com/python/egenix-mx-base-3.1.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf egenix-mx-base-3.1.3.tar.gz
cd egenix-mx-base-3.1.3
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching Python2.7 virtualenv to Python2.6 solved the problem.